# Core Animation: Frame Rate

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos, core-animation

I'm currently working on a project where we're implementing some Core Animation to resize / move elements. We've noticed on many Macs the frame rate drops significantly during these animations, although they're rather simple. Here's an example:

```
 // Set some additional attributes for the animation.
    [theAnim setDuration:0.25];    // Time
    [theAnim setFrameRate:0.0];
    [theAnim setAnimationCurve:NSAnimationEaseInOut];

    // Run the animation.
    [theAnim startAnimation];
    [self performSelector:@selector(endAnimation) withObject:self afterDelay:0.25];
```

Does explicitly stating the frame rate (say 60.0, instead of leaving it at 0.0) put more priority on threads etc, therefor possibly raising frame rate? Is there a better way to animate these altogether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The documentation for NSAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAnimation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says

> A frame rate of 0.0 means to go as fast as possible ...
> The frame rate is not guaranteed

As fast as possible should, reasonably, be the same as 60 fps.

---

## Using Core Animation instead of NSAnimation

NSAnimation is not really a part of Core Animation (it's a part of AppKit). I would recommend trying Core Animation for the animation instead.

1. Adding QuartzCore.framework to your project
2. Importing <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> in your file
3. Setting `- (void)setWantsLayer:(BOOL)flag` to YES on the views you are animating
4. Switch to Core Animation for the animation something like

from the duration of your animation above it looks like "implicit animations" (just changing the property of the layer) may be best for you. If, however you want more control you could use explicit animations, something like this:

```
CABasicAnimation * moveAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"frame"];
[moveAnimation setDuration:0.25];
// There is no frame rate in Core Animation
[moveAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction funtionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[moveAnimation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:yourOldFrame]]
[moveAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:yourNewFrame]];

// To do stuff when the animation finishes, become the delegate (there is no protocol)
[moveAnimation setDelegate:self];

// Core Animation only animates (not changes the value so it needs to be set as well)
[theViewYouAreAnimating setFrame:yourNewFrame];

// Add the animation to the layer that you
[[theViewYouAreAnimating layer] addAnimation:moveAnimation forKey:@"myMoveAnimation"];
```

Then in for callbacks you implement

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)isFinished {
    // Check the animation and perform whatever you want here
    // if isFinished then the animation completed, otherwise it 
    // was cancelled.
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! Great tip David thanks - after implementing this the performance isn't even comparable to NSAnimation. Much, much faster